# print 2 list items on the same line

Tags: python, list

I have two lists:

```
a=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b=[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

I need to print the first 3 items of the list on the same line.
The output should look like this:

```
1 6
2 7
3 8
```

I have tried this code but it just prints everything in a row:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    print(a[i])
for j in range(len(b)):
    print(b[j])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If length is fixed and you only want the first three from each list:

```
a=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b=[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

for i in range(3):
   print("{} {}".format(a[i], b[i]))
```

Outputs:

```
1 6
2 7
3 8
```

---

If you want all the items, but lists can be different length:

```
a=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
b=[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

for i in range( min(len(a), len(b)) ):
   print("{} {}".format(a[i], b[i]))
```

Outputs:

```
1 6
2 7
3 8
4 9
5 10
```

Comment: I receive IndexError: list index out of range. What could be the reason?

Comment: The first bit of code I posted will produce that error if one of your lists has less than 3 items

Answer (score 4):

Use `zip` if the lists are always the same size

```
for x in zip(a, b):
    print(*x)
```

Or `itertools.zip_longest` if not

```
for x in itertools.zip_longest(a, b):
    print(*x)
```

Output

```
1 6
2 7
3 8
4 9
5 10
```

Note that in case of unequal lists the shorter list will pad `None`. You can replace it with other default value with `fillvalue` parameter

```
itertools.zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=default_value)
```

Comment: Note: `zip_longest` also takes an optional parameter for the default value to use when filling the tuples. E.g. `itertools.zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=0)`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this

```
for i in zip(a,b):
    print(*i)
```

This will also allow for lists to be of different lengths

Answer (score 0):

This prints the output you are looking for:

```
for i in range(3):
    print(a[i],b[i])
```

Comment: With this code i also receive IndexError: list index out of range. What could be the reason?

Comment: That's possible when your list does not have at least 3 elements